# Getting error while doing JNDI lookup for EJB in websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, ejb, lookup, classnotfoundexception

My application is getting deployed and loggers also shows the mapping for all the EJBs.
But while doing look up for EJB, it is giving error stating
EJBMDOrchestr E   CNTR0075E: The user-provided class "xxx.xxx.xxx.EJSRemoteStatelessxxx_a265e910" needed by the EnterpriseBean could not be found or loaded.
[1/10/23 17:48:57:004 IST] 00000144 SharedEJBRunt E   WSVR0068E: Attempt to start EnterpriseBean xxx#xxx.jar#xxfailed with exception: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: Bean class xxx.xxx.xxx.EJSRemoteStatelessxxx_a265e910 could not be found or loaded
In above class name EJSRemoteStateless and _a265e910 is not configured in calling part.

I have added ejb-jar.xml, ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi and ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi in META-INF

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Looks like you are using old EJBs with remote interfaces and you forgot to "deploy" the beans. (generate stubs and skeletons). If you are deploying via web console, there is option to deploy EJBs during installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WebSphere, classes that use a naming convention like `EJSRemoteStatelessxxx_a265e910` are deployment artifacts. These artifacts are generated dynamically as needed for EJB 3.x applications. However, older EJB applications were required to use the EJBDeploy command. EJBDeploy may be used prior to application install or the option to run EJBDeploy during install may also be used.

Starting with WebSphere 8.5.5.16, the use of EJBDeploy is no longer required for EJB applications that do not include EJB Entity beans.

To avoid the `CNTR0075E` error, either use EJBDeploy to generate the deployment artifacts or upgrade to WebSphere 8.5.5.16 or later.

For more information about EJBDeploy :
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=reference-ejbdeploy-command

For information about making EJBDeploy optional for EJB 2.x applications:
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH12563